# How can I help pnpm find its global directory?

Tags: pnpm

I've got a clean install of pnpm v8.8.0 on Windows 11. When I try to intall a global package I get:

```
ERR_PNPM_NO_GLOBAL_BIN_DIR  Unable to find the global bin directory
```

I've tried `pnpm setup --force`. Nothing changes. I've looked at the pnpm install instructions, nothing. How can I start using pnpm?

Answer (score 3):

This is a Windows issue. The pnpm install creates a `PNPM_HOME` environment variable, but this is not available to terminals until you sign out and sign back into Windows.

Comment: It's not only a Windows issue. I have the same problem on MacOS Sonoma.

Comment: It was on Mac too. Just close terminal and reopen

Comment: This is also happening in a Docker container, when the Dockerfile contains a `RUN npnm setup` line.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when trying to update `pnpm`. For me, the issue was that I had installed `pnpm` with `npm`, [which caused global directories to not be set up properly.](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/4658#issuecomment-1787502079)

If you installed `pnpm` with `npm`, you also need to update with `npm`.

To update pnpm: `npm i -g pnpm`

Answer (score 0):

Just need to close the terminals if more then one  and your Vscode and try again it will work  pnpm install and what you want to install
and at last --global

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).